# Eigenvalues and similar matrices problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ with all its eigenvalues equal to $1$. Prove that $A$ is similar to $A^2$.

The attempt at a solution.

If all its eigenvalues are equal to $1$, then there is a basis of eigenvectors and a linear transformation $f$ such that $Id_n=A=|f|_B$

In order for $A$ to be similar to $A^2$, the two matrices have to represent the same linear transformation with respecto to different basis, call B the basis associated to $A$ and $B'$ the one with $A^2$, then $A=C(B',B)A^2C(B,B')$.

But $Id_n=A$ so $A^2=(Id_n)^2=Id_n=A$, from here it follows immediately that the two matrices are similar. I am sure there must be something wrong in what I've done, otherwise the exercise is trivially solved. I would appreciate any help and corrections.

Comment: Your third and fourth lines are false: who said that if all the eigenvalues are one then the matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know why I've automatically thought that there had to be a basis of eigenvectors. Then I have no idea why the original statement implies $A \sim A^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is similar to a matrix which is made of Jordan blocks of the form
$$ B =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 0\\
  &   &   &   & \ddots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It suffices to prove the statement for one such block $B$, say it is $k \times k$. Note that $k \times k$ matrices similar to $B$ can be characterized as matrices with all eigenvalues $1$, for which the space of eigenvectors has dimension $1$.

Now
$$ B^2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
  &   &   &   & \ddots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $B^2$ satisfies the condition above, it is similar to $B$.